# using emacs shell with gnu screen?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs

How can I use a bash shell in emacs (M-x shell) when I am trying to connect restart a GNU screen session (on a remote ssh connection)? When I try it, I get:

```
avilella@remote-machine-002~$ bash
avilella@remote-machine-002 ~ > screen -RD
Clear screen capability required.
```

If I try it on a bog-standard terminal, I can restart the same screen session without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say 'good luck'.  From what I remember, and what I just tried, `emacs` does not handle full terminal support under the `shell` command.  For example, in an emacs shell, I try:

```
$ less /etc/hosts
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
/etc/hosts (press RETURN)
```

Then `less` begins to act like it is a dumb terminal (`TERM=dumb less /etc/hosts` from a regular terminal).

I'm sure that you can set terminal settings inside emacs using elisp, but that doesn't mean that the `shell` applet will honor them.

Comment: An Emacs shell buffer does not use a pseudo-terminal, so I agree with @Arcege here.  You may have some luck using the `terminal-emulator` command, which does allocate a pty.